# Another "slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method" thread

Tags: python

Trying to debug a Python script, and keep being this error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Since the file names have no integers... this doesn't seem to make any sense.
Any suggestions?

```
import os
inputFolder = "d:\\full"
outputFolder = "d:\\clean"
for path, dir, file in os.walk(inputFolder):
    for filename in file:
        if filename.endswith(".jpeg", ".jpg"):
            inputPath = inputFolder + os.sep + filename
            print inputPath
```

Comment: Is this whole of your code?

Comment: `str.endswith` expects a tuple instead of multiple arguments.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really about discussion threads, it's clear questions and clear answers. The discussion is usually to clarify the question if the asker hasn't been clear enough.

Comment: At the very least, you should *include the full traceback* (which shows the line with the problem), formatted as a code block rather than a blockquote.

Comment: Maybe if people put as much effort into trying to answer questions, rather than getting worked up over formatting, this might be a useful site.
As it is, I tried to be as short, clear and precise as possible.
And yes, I put up all of my code and the complete error message, @Kasra.

Comment: @WombatBob no, you didn't - the traceback is missing *the actual line that caused the error*, which would have made it much easier for people to figure out what the problem actually was. Also the code is **not** as short as possible - my answer demonstrates that a single line is sufficient to replicate the error, which you should have attempted to cut your code down to.

Comment: @WombatBob Effort? [I don't think it means what you think it means](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk).

Comment: Well... how does one find "the actual line that caused the error"?
Should I make one up? hit my computer until it spits one out?

Comment: If you had saved your program in a file, the full traceback would show exactly which actual line caused the error. The traceback you get from the REPL is somewhat less informative.

Answer (score 9):

You are misusing [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). The second and third* parameters are `start` and `end`, which are used to index into the string, **not** additional strings to check for. By default these are both `None`, hence checking the whole string:

```
>>> 'foo'[None:None]
'foo'
```

This explains the seemingly-confusing error message; Python is trying to check `filename['.jpg':None].endswith('.jpeg')`, which clearly doesn't make any sense. Instead, to check for multiple strings, pass *a single tuple* as the first parameter:

```
if filename.endswith((".jpeg", ".jpg")):
                   # ^ note extra parentheses
```

Demo:

```
>>> 'test.jpg'.endswith('.jpg', '.jpeg')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    'test.jpg'.endswith('.jpg', '.jpeg')
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
>>> 'test.jpg'.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg'))
True
```

* *(or third and fourth, as `instance.method(arg)` can be written `Class.method(instance, arg)`)*