# Move .png on desktop to new directory

Tags: python

Relatively new to python, trying to move files based on type from one directory to another.

```
import shutil
import os
source = 'C:\Users\home\Desktop'
Unsorted = 'C:\Users\home\Desktop\'
Sorted = 'B:\Pictures'
file = os.listdir(source)
for f in file("Unsorted"):
    if file.endswith(".png",".jpg"):
        print(os.path.join("Sorted", file))
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Edit**
Thank you for the help and the links. I really appreciate it. I am reading automatetheboringstuff, and    Modern Python Cookbook (2018).

```
import os
source = 'C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop'
sorted = 'B:\\Pictures'
    for f in os.listdir(source):
        if f.endswith((".png",".jpg",".jpeg")):
        print(os.path.join(sorted, f))
```

I believe it works, since I am not getting any errors, but it's not moving the files. It seems to work here: [link](http://prntscr.com/i2ht88). Maybe it doesn't work between drives? Anyway, thank you!

**EDIT** I got it to work!

```
import os
import shutil

source = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop')
sort = os.path.join('B:\\Pictures')

for f in os.listdir(source):
    if f.endswith((".png",".jpg",".jpeg")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), sort)
```

Thank you everyone for your help! I hope you guys have a great rest of your day! Thanks. :D

Comment: try for f in os.listdir(source):

Comment: Apart from the fact that \ has special meaning in strings and should be escaped by another \, what is the problem with this code?

Comment: What do you think `file("Unsorted")` means? Just `file` is an unsorted list already (though don't use the reserved keyword `file` for a variable of yours).

Comment: Probably switch to forward slashes or `r'...'` strings for those pesky Windows file names with backslashes. These ones look safe but Python will generally do unpleasant things with backslashes in strings.

Comment: The argument to `.endswith` needs to be a single string or else an iterable.

Comment: `os.listdir` doesn't work like that, you can check out the doc here https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite There are many problems but I don't see how the usage of `os.listdir` is wrong or misdirected. Could you explain, please? Also, linking to Python 2 documentation seems like an increasingly bad idea.

Comment: @tripleee well from the given code it seems like @Gabriel thinks `os.listdir` returns some callable object which returns a sequence or a generator  when called with a string, which is not what `os.listdir` does at all... linking to a documentation as part of a **comment** is shorthand for explaining the subject... if i gave an actual answer i could give an example and explain how it works but i didn't...

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now; thanks for clarifying. For quickly googled documentation links, replacing the /2/ with /3/ in a link to python.org often gets you the current documentation instead of the doco for the moribund version which was supposed to be end-of-lifed in a few months from now (but got a couple more years of intensive care after all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the comments inline.

```
#import shutil  # commented out as this is not used for anything here
import os
# use r'...' strings for file names with backslashes (or use forward slashes instead)
source = r'C:\Users\home\Desktop'
#Unsorted = r'C:\Users\home\Desktop\'  # also not used
Sorted = r'B:\Pictures'
# listdir produces an unsorted list of files so no need to muck with it 
for f in os.listdir(source):
    # you had the wrong variable name here, and missing parens around the tuple
    if f.endswith((".png",".jpg")):
        # again, the variable is f
        # and of course "Sorted" is just a string, you want the variable
        print(os.path.join(Sorted, f))
```

Some general advice:

- Python has good documentation and is easy to play around with; just starting up Python and typing in a fragment of your program lets you try things until you can see what to write in your program to make it do what you want, without guesswork, typos, or unfounded expectations.
- Don't use reserved keywords for your variables. Understand the difference between a string and a variable name (and a keyword).
- Many of the things you had wrong are extremely common beginner errors. A bit of googling (especially with an error message or a phrase describing what's not working) will very often lead you to an excellent answer on Stack Overflow explaining exactly what's wrong and how to fix it.
- Thus, don't cram too much into a single question. Most of the time, if your question is specific enough, you don't even have to ask it once you see what's wrong.

To concretize with an example, in the Python interactive REPL, maybe you are actually wondering whether `endswith` works with an uppercase file name, so you try it:

```
>>> 'PANGEA.PNG'.endswith(".png",".jpg")
```

This gives you a somewhat incredulous message that "slice indices must be integers" which isn't very helpful by itself (until you understand what it's trying to say -- `endswith` wants a "suffix" argument and an (optional) "start" argument, which is then used to "slice" the string; and `".jpg"` isn't a valid value for `start`, so slicing fails because of that) but very easy to search for -- [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408680/another-slice-indices-must-be-integers-or-none-or-have-an-index-method-thr) is literally my first google hit for [the search `endswith "slice indices must be integers"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=endswith+%22slice+indices+must+be+integers%22&) and so you figure out what was wrong with your attempt, and what the error message is telling you, and now you go ahead and fix one of the small bugs in your code so far, and proceed with the next experiment (maybe check that `os.path.join("Sorted", "PANGEA.PNG")` looks like what you expect?)